# Flexslider Image overlap on smaller screens

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, flexslider

I am attempting to make a webpage mobile responsive however the images in the flexslider on smaller screens, goes askew. Whether it was loaded or scaled down, the image to the right encroaches on the current image.

I would post an image but I need more reputation points.

I am trying to figure out how to push the current image being viewed over so that the edge of the next picture isn't being shown prematurely.

Comment: Show us your code ;)

Comment: The css in question is just this:

.flexslider{
    .slides:first-child img{
        height: auto;
    }

    .flex-control-thumbs{
        margin-top: 20px; 
        
        li{
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
    
    .flex-direction-nav{
        display:none;
    }
  
  }

Comment: The javascript is just calling the flexslider and getting it to scroll through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to add a media query to apply margin-left at a certain point. just couldn't find the rule to target for a little while:

```
.slides:first-child img{
    height: auto;

}

//fixes the bug where the second image appears on the right on smaller screens
@media (max-width: 991px){
  .slides:first-child img{
    margin-left: 40px;
  }
}

.flex-control-thumbs{
    margin-top: 20px;
    li{
        cursor: pointer;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
}
```